# Using PyTorch for scientific computation

Tags: pytorch

I would like to use PyTorch as a scientific computation package. It has much to recommend it in that respect - its Tensors are basically GPU-accelerated numpy arrays, and its `autograd` mechanism is potentially useful for a lot of things besides neural networks.

However, the available tutorials and documentation seem strongly geared towards quickly getting people up and running using it for machine learning. Although there is lots of good information available on the `Tensor` and `Variable` classes (and I understand that material reasonably well), the `nn` and `optim` packages always seem to be introduced by example rather than by explaining the API, which makes it hard to figure out exactly what's going on.

My main question at this point is whether I can use the `optim` package without also using the `nn` package, and if so how to do so. Of course I can always implement my simulations as subclasses of `nn.Module` even though they are not neural networks, but I would like to understand what happens under the hood when I do this, and what benefits/drawbacks it would give for my particular application.

More broadly, I would appreciate pointers to any resource that gives more of a logical overview of the API (for `nn` and `optim` specifically), rather than just presenting examples.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the reasons for the down votes, so that I can avoid making the same mistake in future. (If the issue is that I want to use a library for something other than its intended purpose, please note that one of the PyTorch developers has a presentation on YouTube titled "PyTorch:  Framework for fast, dynamic deep learning and scientific computing", so it's not *that* crazy.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial self-answer to the specific question about using `optim` without using `nn`. The answer is, yes, you can do that. In fact, from looking at the source code, the `optim` package doesn't know anything about `nn` and only cares about Variables and tensors.

The documentation gives the following incomplete example:

```
optimizer = optim.Adam([var1, var2], lr = 0.0001)
```

and then later:

```
for input, target in dataset:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(input)
    loss = loss_fn(output, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

The function `model` isn't defined anywhere and looks like it might be something to do with `nn`, but in fact it can just be a Python function that computes `output` from `input` using `var1` and `var2` as parameters, as long as all the intermediate steps are done using Variables so that it can be differentiated. The call to `optimizer.step()` will update the values of `var1` and `var2` automatically.

In terms of the structure of PyTorch overall, it seems that `optim` and `nn` are independent of one another, with `nn` being basically just a convenient way to chain differentiable functions together, along with a library of such functions that are useful in machine learning. I would still appreciate pointers to a good technical overview of the whole package, though.